# AttributeError when using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, attributeerror

I'm writing a script to generate JSON files and I'm running into a bit of an issue.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = requests.get('https://www.perfectimprints.com/custom-promos/20492/Beach-Balls.html')
source = BeautifulSoup(url.text, 'html.parser')

product_feed = source.find('div', id_="pageBody")

products = product_feed.find_all('div', class_="product_wrapper")

single_product = products[0]

product_name = single_product.find('div', class_="product_name")
product_name = product_name.a.text

sku = single_product.find('div', class_="product_sku")
sku = sku.text

def get_product_details(product):
  product_name = product.find('div', class_="product_name").a.text
  sku = single_product.find('div', class_="product_sku").text
  return {
    "product_name": product_name,
    "sku": sku
  }

all_products = [get_product_details(product) for product in products]
print(all_products)
```

The error message I'm getting in return is: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scrape.py", line 9, in <module>
    products = product_feed.find_all('div', class_="product_wrapper")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'`

From my reading it's because it isn't finding anything with the `product_wrapper` class, but that doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `product_feed`, remove it and change next line to:

```
products = source.find_all('div', class_="product_wrapper")
```

Can verify at the end: `print(len(all_products))` `48`

Comment: This did it. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `product_feed = source.find('h1', id_="pageBody")` is returning `None`. I tried your code and `product_feed = source.find_all('h1')` returns only 1 item with no id information.

Comment: Thank you. I fixed that issue, but it's still returning an error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scrape.py", line 9, in <module>
    products = product_feed.find_all('div', class_="product_wrapper")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'`

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the source code of the site, the element with id="pageBody" is a `div`, not a `h1`. So when you use `source.find` it returns `None`. Try:

```
...
product_feed = source.find('div', id_="pageBody")
...
```

Comment: Thank you. I fixed that issue, but it's still returning an error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scrape.py", line 9, in <module>
    products = product_feed.find_all('div', class_="product_wrapper")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'`